# Scrape data in html table form without class id using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-table, extract

I am new to web-scraping and I am trying to extract the data from html tables and save it as a csv file. I already tried few solution but I still can't figure out how to solve it.

I tried to extract all the information from the `td` tag. Picture below is the example of the segment of the code. I tried to extract all the data that been highlight

[image]

This is what I have done so far:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://focos.hpb.gov.sg/eservices/ENCF/FoodAnalysis.aspx?p=1")

bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
html.close()

filename = "food.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers ="name, desc, portion, serving, measure, energy, protein, totFat, saturatedFat, DietaryFibre, Carbs, Cholesterol, Sodium\n"
f.write(headers)


table= bs.find('span', attrs={"id":"lblTable"})
table_body = bs.find('tbody')

rows = table_body.findAll('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols=row.findAll('td')
    cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
    print(cols)

f.close()
```

However, this code return an error which is:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

I would really appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: Are you able to get the content of the page through your code? It seems a direct hyperlink is not working on the browser, unless i select the food serving etc from dropdown.

Comment: It seems there's no span in the html that you are loading.

Comment: @instinct246 i already try to print the content of html. But the output is [ ]. I'm not sure if i'm do it correctly. Do you hv any suggestion on how to resolve it?

Comment: @BartBarnard do you think that it is possible for me to web-scrapping this html webpages? if yes, would you teach me on how to do it? i would appreciate it if you want to share with me.

Comment: The reason may be your query ( in the web page related to any food) does not build a direct hyperlink. So the fault 'may not' be with your code but the hyperlink...I will check more..

Comment: @instinct246 thank you in advanced! I really hope you that can help me T.T

Comment: `https://focos.hpb.gov.sg/eservices/ENCF/FoodAnalysis.aspx?p=1` do not return page you want. Check it manually in browser.

Comment: @Sers I'm sorry. But what do you mean by check it manually in browser? is it impossible for me to do web-scrap?

Comment: @Izzati There are lots of tutorials online for scraping with python. E.g. 

uing lxml: https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/scrape/
using BeautifulSoup: https://codeburst.io/web-scraping-101-with-python-beautiful-soup-bb617be1f486

A good general introduction can be found at https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-html-tables-with-python-c9baba21059